# I get totally different solutions from Glpk and Rglpk

Tags: r, optimization, glpk

With R version 4.0.4 (2021-02-15) using the GLPK callable library version 5.0 I am getting a solution with maximum objective value *lower than* the one I get by solving the same problem directly running GLPSOL--GLPK LP/MIP Solver 5.0. Yes, both return status OK (i.e., 0).

This happens both on Linux (versions mentioned above) and on Windows (R version 4.2.1 and GLPK callable library 4.65 compared to GLPSOL--GLPK LP/MIP Solver  version 4.65).

Both of these run on 64-bit machines.

Even more strangely, older versions of R and GLPK on 32-bit MX Linux gave both identical solution which matches the one produced by the GLPSOL solvers above (and which also appears published as *the solution*). Unfortunately I have no longer access to that machine and I cannot recall the exact versions of R or GLPK but I recall that both were of year 2015.

Is there *any* reasonable explanation other than that something is erroneous with the Rglpk interface to Glpk?

Thank you in advance,

/Samig

Comment: Double check the input is the same.

Comment: Yes, it is the same! I get the result of direct Glpk use if I run the code with R version 3.4.4 and using the Glpk callable library 4.65 *but* totally different result with R version 4.0.4 and Glpk callable library 5.0.

Comment: Can you show the solver logs?

Comment: I can provide a small example both in R and in MathProg. Would  it be OK to add these as comments here?

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved!

The error was a consequence of different behavior of `data.matrix` for different R versions (!?!?). Once I replaced it with `sapply` in preparing the data, I've got correct results from the solver for all R versions.